# A way to calculate DateTime intersection where NULL is possible

Tags: php, datetime, comparison, limesurvey

**Background**

I'm integrating [Limesurvey](http://www.limesurvey.org) with an application, where new survey tokens are added directly to the Limesurvey database. Before insertion can be done, I need to check that a given set of tokens (with `validfrom` and `validuntil` attributes) in Limesurvey does not intersect with a given range of dates (`DateTime`).

**The problem**

Since Limesurveys token `validfrom` and `validuntil` attributes can be `NULL`, a simple comparison of `DateTime` can't be done, or can it?

(A Limesurvey `validfrom/validuntil` `NULL` value implies "always")

**What I have**

A php class that checks if the Limesurvey attributes are `NULL` (or not), and returning a calculation of the intersection as needed.

Code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3vp-j3b

(It's what's inside the `foreach` loop, **lines 34-70**, that are interesting here)

**What I ask**

Is there a way to improve/optimise this method, given that the comparison values are special?

Comment: I do not get the question: What and why exactly do you want to optimize?

Comment: @BurninLeo OK, wasn't clear enough... I'm mostly curious to whether there's a smoother way to acheive the same result.

Comment: Depends on *what* you want smoother. If you replace the ''new DateTime'' by a non-object solution, for example, the script becomes faster but less readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace null with a possible first and last date to ease comparing:

```php
if (is_null($token['validfrom']) {
    $token_validfrom = new DateTime('0000-01-01 00:00:00');
} else {
    $token_validfrom = new DateTime($token['validfrom']);
}
if (is_null($token['validuntil']) {
    $token_validuntil = new DateTime('9999-12-31 23:23:59');
} else {
    $token_validuntil = new DateTime($token['validuntil']);
}
```

This way only your last line of comparison should be necessary:

```
return ($validfrom == $token_validfrom) || ($validfrom > $token_validfrom ? $validfrom < $token_validuntil : $token_validfrom < $validuntil);
```

Comment: That's actually quite nifty. In C# there's a `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue`, but I reckon that's not the case with php. I think I'll go with 0001-01-01 for the "from" value, as that's used in C#. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx